# Snowflake Kafka Connector fails with NoClassDefFoundError for BouncyCastleProvider

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The error message in connector 0.5.1 is

ERROR WorkerConnector{id=Snowflake-kafka-test} Error while starting connector
(org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConnector:119)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by downloading the Bouncy Castle provider jar file from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on and placing it under the libs folder.

Comment: Yes that fixes it. The snowflake docs updated to include this as a step.

Answer (score 0):

According [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-kafka-connector/issues/63) it's fixed on 10/21/19 and will be in the next release

Comment: Version 0.5.2 of Kafka connector released on 10/22

Answer (score 0):

If anyone sees this issue, here is the [Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html#download-the-kafka-connector-files).

We have also added tests which points out where to put this jar files.
If you are using encrypted private key as your authentication mechanism (Which is recommended), put in following directories

For Apache Kafka:
`/lib` directory

For Confluent Kafka
`/share/java/kafka`

Along with putting inside the `usr/local/share/kafka/plugins` - same directory where Snowflake's Kafka Connector plugins is kept.